# What is the "?:" operator in Java? E.g. sum += digit > 9 ? digit - 9 : digit;

Tags: java

Pretty much what the title says, I have a hard time comprehending this expression, would be grateful if anyone explained the idea behind this expression.

Comment: Try grouping the terms in parentheses and see if that makes it clearer.

Comment: Which part of the expression confuses you? Would parenthesis help? `sum += (digit > 9 ? digit - 9 : digit);`. Expression uses `>` comparison operator, `-` subtraction operator, `? :` ternary conditional operator, and `+=` additive-assignment operator. Which of these don't you know?

Comment: In short, it is a way of writing if-statement, just like how you write if-statement in MS Excel.

Comment: Read about Java Ternary Operators https://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018

Answer (score 6):

This is ternary operation it is the same as a if else in one expression;

The statement: `sum += digit > 9 ? digit - 9 : digit;`

Is the same as:

```
if (digit > 9)
  sum += digit - 9;
else
  sum += digit;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a [Java Ternary Operator](https://www.journaldev.com/963/java-ternary-operator)

Basically if the `Sum + digit` is greater than 9 than sum will equal `digit-9` OR if not it will just equal `digit`

So this is same as

```
if (digit > 9)
  sum += digit - 9;
else
  sum += digi
```

Comment: Not quite. If digit > then `sum = sum + digit -9` else `sum = sum + digit`

Comment: Oh yes, you're correct. I forgot to account for the `+=` operation. Thank you @scrappedcola for catching my mistake and correcting it.